# Maven project setup

Tags: java, maven

I currently got a project with flat structure with following dependency;

```
    Core  --> core.jar
            Service --> WAR
            Domain --> domain.jar
                    Web  -> WAR
```

Pretty much, everything depends on core.jar from Core module, and Web depend on domain jar from Domain module, which is depend on Core.

I'm planning to convert this to Maven, I need some feed back on possible best structure I should use.

Choices I have is to keep the current structure then produce jar files from each module and use them as part of dependency with maven. Or
Re structure the modules in some sort of hierarchy, where I need some help.

I want to follow some sort of best practice use of Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a parent pom, which you can use to keep the dependencies managed across the child projects. Then set up each of your jar/war artifacts as modules.

Each module sources its dependencies using the normal `<dependencies>` in the module pom.

so have this:

```
parent-project [pom]: 
    modules: 
       core [jar]
       domain [jar] - depends on core
       service [war] - depends on core
       web [war] - depends on domain
```

And as a concrete example, here's a sample of one of my projects:

**parent pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>myproject-parent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.6</jersey.version>
        <jsonunit.version>1.5.5</jsonunit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>api-client</module>
        <module>load-tests</module>
        <module>regression-tests</module>
    </modules>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.10</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5-beta</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.22</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-unit</artifactId>
                <version>${jsonunit.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-unit-fluent</artifactId>
                <version>${jsonunit.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**api-client**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>api-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <xmlunit.version>2.0.0-alpha-03</xmlunit.version>
    </properties>


    <name>api-client</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlunit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-matchers</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlunit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-unit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-unit-fluent</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        ... snip ...
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

and finally load-tests, which depends on api-client

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>load-tests</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <name>load-tests</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-client</artifactId>
            <version>${parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
     ... snip ...
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what I m trying to demonstrate will match your choice.

1. Create a POM Project as Parent
2. Add each jar and war as Module

> Choices I have is to keep the current structure then produce jar files from each module and use them as part of dependency with maven.